# Two routes after namespace refactoring MVC WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

i renamed my namespace for my whole project. Everything is still working fine, but my WebAPI is now finding two routes for my controllers.

```
Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'department'.
This can happen if the route that services this request ('api/{controller}/{id}') found multiple controllers defined with the same name but differing namespaces, which is not supported.

The request for 'department' has found the following matching controllers:
A***.P***.Benutzerverwaltung.Jo***MVC.Controllers.DepartmentController
A***.Benutzerverwaltung.API.Controllers.DepartmentController
```

So i renamed the first namespace into the second, i searched everywhere for the old namespace, but nothing was found. So, what could i do?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Did you rename a referenced project also?

Comment: yes, there are three projects in my solution and i renamed two

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So, what could i do?

Go to the `bin` folder of your web application and delete the old assemblies. ASP.NET loads all assemblies that are present in the `bin` folder. So if you are saying that you renamed some class library project reference, the old assembly is still physically there.

Comment: I still did that. I cant imagine where ASP.NET find the first route. There is no folder, file, reference or anything else with that name Jo***MVC

Comment: There must be such file left in your `bin` folder. There's no other explanation. Navigate with your Windows Explorer to the `bin` folder of your ASP.NET MVC application and delete ALL files. Then rebuild.

Comment: now it works, after the second delete all files and rebuild. oO Thank you :)

Comment: One would assume, that the `cleanup` option in the project's context menu would do this, but no, still had to delete the dlls manually...